# Meteor Looping data

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I stuck with 2 problems first how to loop and update in Mini MongoDb like this. And How to get _id for update it.

```js
var data = [ 
{ 
    "key" : "North America" , 
    "values" : [ 
        [ 1025409600000 , 23.041422681023] , 
        [ 1028088000000 , 19.854291255832]
    ]
}, 
{ 
    "key" : "Africa" , 
    "values" : [ 
        [ 1025409600000 , 7.9356392949025] , 
        [ 1028088000000 , 7.4514668527298]
    ]
}];
```

And this function for loop BUT it just stop at very first looping

```js
for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    Looping.insert({
        key:data[i].key,
        values:[]
    });
    var looping_id = Looping._id;
    for(var j = 0; j < data[i].values.length; j++) {
        Looping.update({
            _id: looping_id
        },
        {
            $addToSet: {values: data[i].values[j]}
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `Looping` is a collection, you could insert your items with this:

```js
_.each(data, function(item) {
  Looping.insert(item);
});
```

However, because you are using `$addToSet`, I'm guessing that the values could be non-unique. In that case you can try:

```js
_.each(data, function(item) {
  var id = Looping.insert({key: item.key});

  _.each(item.values, function(value) {
    Looping.update(id, {$addToSet: {values: value}});
  });
});
```

Notes:

- The id of the inserted item is returned by the call to `insert`, it is not held in the collection object.
- If you have a lot of items to insert, you should consider de-duplicating each set of `values` prior to the insert so you can avoid all of the updates.